# Visual Studio Express Crashing on Build (F5)

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Complete beginners question here, literally.

I'm interested in developing Windows 8 Apps so I've just downloaded the development tools and installed them following the starting guide found here: [Part 1 - Create a "Hello, world" App](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986964.aspx).

I followed the instructions exactly however Step 2 does not work, when I try and run the app. I hit F5 and then says in the Output module that the deployment is successful but the app does not run as indicated in the tutorial. I left it for 10 mins but the entire Visual Studio program was unresponsive so I ended the task in task manager.

The app did get added to the Windows 8 start screen and I CAN run it from there.

I then opened the program again and tried F5 once more, again this time the Output module indiates "Deployment Started.." but then the program crashes again.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? I literally haven't changed a single line of code.

Also cancelling the build does not work.

Thanks for any hep!

UPDATE: In case it is confusing I use "Build" in the title because that is the term from the tutorial, I have noticed that under the menu's F5 is actually titled "Debugging" and "Build" is F7, I'm not sure if the tutorial has made a mistake, either way it does not affect my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple re-start managed to fix this issue however I still have no idea what caused it!